Curve, depth - question
why is this happening? why is the shape not round but oval? if i press Alt + S the shape will become normal, but the slope will change, and I don't need the slope to change. I want to understand where the error is, why this happens?


Push Ctrl+A and make sure your scale is applied.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
